# Ehcache in Spring not find the name?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I have a Spring Rest app with hibernate and MySQL.

The ehcache for a Service work in test and fail in tomcat.

**Spring EhCache**

```
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ehcache"
 class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache/cache.xml" />
        <property name="shared" value="true" />
   </bean>
```

**Context**

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
  ...
<import resource="classpath:spring/spring-cache.xml" />
```

**Cache.xml**

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true" maxBytesLocalHeap="150M">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <cache name="byCategory" eternal="false" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" transactionalMode="off">

    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

**Hibernate Cache** Only in Prod

```
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
    </prop>
```

I have a facade with one mtehod has the annotation

*@Cacheable(value = { "byCategory" }, key = "#ids.toString()")*

This run ok in Test because the hibernate ehcache is not used, but in prod the CacheManager dont load de names that I defined in xml.

Can merge names of hibernate and owns?

Comment: Hibernate and Spring based caching are different beasts and as such the caches aren't shareable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use multiple `CacheManager` in the same application.

Make sure however that they have different names. Given your setup, it might be easiest to test first by naming the `CacheManager` you configure using `classpath:ehcache/cache.xml`.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
<ehcache name="aName"
  <!-- Your configuration -->
</ehcache>
```